# How token based authentication helps in cors, cdn, CSRF , mobile ready?

Tags: authentication, session-cookies, http-token-authentication

I was reading articles about token based authentication.
And when I was going through this article "[Cookies Vs Tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/)", I did not understand the following four points (I have asked my doubts below each of the quoted points)

> Cross-domain / CORS: cookies + CORS don't play well across different
>   domains. A token-based approach allows you to make AJAX calls to any
>   server, on any domain because you use an HTTP header to transmit the
>   user information.

Why now there will not be cors problem ? What if someone one from the neighboring tab in the browser steals your token(because in javascript of that domain there is code which can clearly tell where the token is stored and how it is retrieved) and starts making 
requests ?
And more over it is said "cookies + cors" . why is it said that cookie and cors don't play well ?

> CDN: you can serve all the assets of your app from a CDN (e.g.
>   javascript, HTML, images, etc.), and your server side is just the API.

Why is this an advantage in token based auth systems ? We were using cdn's even when we were doing cookie based authentication right ?
This was because script tags can call scripts from other domains any way right ?

> CSRF: since you are not relying on cookies, you don't need to protect
>   against cross site requests (e.g. it would not be possible to 
>   your site, generate a POST request and re-use the existing
>   authentication cookie because there will be none).

What if someone one from the neighboring tab in the browser(from some other domain) steals your token and starts making 
requests ? I cannot understand this either.

> Mobile ready: when you start working on a native platform (iOS,
>   Android, Windows 8, etc.) cookies are not ideal when consuming a
>   secure API (you have to deal with cookie containers). Adopting a
>   token-based approach simplifies this a lot.

Did not understand it completely . Can someone explain , how?

Answer (score 3):

The linked article is a bit sloppily written and does not properly define and distinguish between the various concepts.

First, you have to define what exactly you mean by "token based". The article does not do that, but it seems it has OAuth 2.0 JWT access tokens with the *Bearer Token Usage* (http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html) in mind. This means that:

- *Bearer* access tokens are used. The upside of bearer tokens (as opposed to MAC token usage) is simplicity of usage -- all a client needs to pass to a server is a token. The downside is that whoever gets hold of such a token is considered its rightful owner, so he can do whatever he wants with it.
- Tokens are passed in the *Authorization* HTTP header, following a specific syntax.

Then you have to define what you really mean by "cookie based" authentication -- which again, the article does not do. A cookie, essentially, is just a transport mechanism to pass data back and forth between client and servers of a specific domain, without the client having to do anything explicitly. So you can really stuff pretty much anything into a cookie -- even OAuth 2 access tokens.

What the author seems to have in mind is server side-managed sessions where a session id is passed in a cookie.

With these definitions in mind, it is possible to answer your questions:

> Cross-domain / CORS: cookies + CORS don't play well across different domains. A token-based approach allows you to make AJAX calls to any server, on any domain because you use an HTTP header to transmit the user information.

This is true, but for different reasons: Cookies are scoped to a specific domain, so as long as you use cookies to pass a session id between clients and servers, you are bound to having to put all servers under one domain. This looks like a limitation, but the true limitation is somewhere else -- when using server side-managed sessions, a session id will only make sense to those servers who have access to the server side session management. Any server outside the domain most likely cannot make any sense of a session id.

A JWT access token, however, is self contained and can be interpreted by other parties as well. This is why access tokens are well suited for cross-domain/cross-service calls.

> CDN: you can serve all the assets of your app from a CDN (e.g. javascript, HTML, images, etc.), and your server side is just the API.

Yes. But this does not really matter in practice because anyting you put into a CDN will most likely not require authentication in the first place -- so this is kind of a silly argument.

> CSRF: since you are not relying on cookies, you don't need to protect against cross site requests (e.g. it would not be possible to your site, generate a POST request and re-use the existing authentication cookie because there will be none).

The danger of cookies w.r.t. CSRF is that they are passed implicitly to the server -- the browser adds a cookie to the request, regardless of whether it was good of rogue code that triggered the request.

When tokens are passed in a cookie, this danger applies to tokens we well. However, when they are passed in a header (as the Bearer Token Usage spec defines), this danger does not exist as the header needs to be added to teh request explicitly, every single time. This makes this approach more CSRF-safe than cookies.

However, when the rogue code can get hold of the token some other way (because it was passed as a URL parameter, for example (which the spec allows), it is still possible to make CSRF attacks with tokens.

> Mobile ready: when you start working on a native platform (iOS, Android, Windows 8, etc.) cookies are not ideal when consuming a secure API (you have to deal with cookie containers). Adopting a token-based approach simplifies this a lot.

Dealing with cookie containers is usually easier than setting up OAuth, so I do not buy into this one.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll try to go through these in as structured a way as possible:

1. **CORS + Cookies**: Cookies were never meant to travel across domains. A cookie must be submitted to the server from its origin, cross-origin cookies don't exist. There is no need to worry about another application accessing the token if it's stored in `localstorage` since that one is site-specific, e.g every site gets it own allotted space of localstorage.
2. I'm not certain about this one. I'd assume they mean an authenticated CDN, e.g you provide a token to get access to the resources
3. Again, the token won't be stolen by a neighbour, because of how `localstorage` works. If you're worried you could actually issue a new token from the server with every response, effectively making one-time use tokens. That way, even if your token is compromised, it is far less likely to work.
4. Cookies are fairly complex structures, and if you one day decide you want to consume your API on a mobile device, it will be much easier to use a token, which is just a string (compared to a structured object)

**The most important difference** is that tokens are stateless, while cookies are not. Cookies will contain information about the authenticated user and context-specific data. A token, on the other hand, is just a string that an API consumer assumes can be used to access restricted data.